# Jquery - addClass div > span

Tags: jquery, addclass

I would like to know, how i can add class at a span last div :

```
<div class="dim-187"><span></span></div>
```

I would like

```
<div class="dim-187"><span class="checked"></span></div>
```

My script for the moment but not working :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#reload-button>span").click(function(){
        $(".dim-277").addClass("checked");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".dim-277 span").addClass("checked");`

Answer (score 0):

Use as, when you click on span it will add

```
<script>
$(function () {
   $(".dim-187>span").click(function(){
       $(this).addClass("checked");
    });
 });
</script>
```